# \cline does not completely work in presence of \multirow

Tags: tables

I'm working on the following table, in which the command `\cline{2-4}` does not draw the horizontal line between `Timed` and `Untimed` entries:

[image]

Can you give me some advice to fix it?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\nocell[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
        \begin{tabular}{|c |c |c |c|}
            \cline{3-4}         
            \nocell{2} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\bfseries\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.0,0.22} \text{Centrality}}}$}\\ 
            \hline
            \cline{3-4}
            \nocell{2} & \cellcolor[rgb] {1.0,0.33,0.64}Centralized  &  \cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.65,0.79} Decentralized\\
            \hline
            \cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.4,0.6,0.8} Untimed & Chapter 3 & Chapter 4\\
            \cline{2-4}
            \multirow{-2}{*}{\bfseries\cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0} Temporality} 
            & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.75,1.0} Timed & Chapter 5 & Chapter 6\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not `\multirow`. What happens if you don't use `\cellcolor`?

Comment: @cfr: Removing the last `\cellcolor` fixes the problem; however, `Timed` cell loses its color.

Comment: It is a known issue. Try searching for solutions. This has been asked several times before in various guises. Also, check by zooming that the line is really not there.

Comment: The aesthetically most pleasing solution would be to simply do away with all interior horizontal and vertical rules...

Comment: Incidentally, what's the purpose of the `$\vcenter{\hbox{...}}$` "wrapper"?

Comment: @Mico: The entries of the table were not vertically aligned in another project because of some clashes between called packages, so this wrapper fixed the problem "in that case".

Comment: Off-topic (but probably still relevant): If one looks closely at the contents of the six colored cells, one notices that they're not centered properly in five cases. (The exception is the "Centralized" cell.) This is happening because of an inappropriate whitespace after the respective `\cellcolor` directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of some horizontal lines adjacent to colored cells not showing up is well known. You should be able to find quite a few postings on this subject on this site.

A more serious issue, aesthetically speaking, is that you appear to be mixing up  two visual metaphors in your table for delimiting cells: (a) drawing of horizontal and vertical lines and (b) using color. I think it's best to stick with one or the other metaphor -- and *not* to use both simultaneously.

Here's a solution that does away with all horizontal and vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}

\begin{tabular}{l ccc}
    %\cline{3-4}         
    && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.0,0.22}Centrality}\\ 
    %\cline{3-4}
    & & \cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.33,0.64}Centralized\phantom  
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.65,0.79}Decentralized\\
    %\hline
    \cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0} 
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.4,0.6,0.8}Untimed 
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.91,0.91,0.91}Chapter 3 
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.91,0.91,0.91}Chapter 4\\
    %\cline{2-4}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\bfseries\cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0}Temporality} 
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.75,1.0}Timed 
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.91,0.91,0.91}Chapter 5 
      & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.91,0.91,0.91}Chapter 6\\
    %\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that I've also omitted the `$\vcenter{\hbox{...}}$` wrapper around the contents of one cell.

Comment: Black-and-white print of this table does not reflect the colors considerably, thereby hiding the nature of the table at all. Such points are the sources of nagging for the thesis committee in some departments! That's why I have stuck at the such mixing.

Comment: As I already stated, that wrapper was used for a special case, by the way.

Comment: @Roboticist - If there's any chance that important copies/versions of the document will show colors either incorrectly or not at all, you may have to rethink the rationale for using colors in the first place. That, or use colors (and shades of gray) that "translate" reasonably well even when rendered in black&white.

Answer (score 2):

Using `hhline` package:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\nocell[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
    \begin{tabular}{|c |c |c |c|}
        \hhline{~~--}           
        \nocell{2} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\bfseries\cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.0,0.22} \text{Centrality}}}$}\\ 
        %\cline{3-4}
        \hhline{~~--}
        \nocell{2} & \cellcolor[rgb] {1.0,0.33,0.64}Centralized  &  \cellcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.65,0.79} Decentralized\\
        \hline
        \cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0} & \cellcolor[rgb]{0.4,0.6,0.8} Untimed & Chapter 3 & Chapter 4\\
        \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}---}
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\bfseries\cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,1.0} Temporality} 
        & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.75,1.0}} Timed & Chapter 5 & Chapter 6\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code immediately after `\cline{2-4}`:

```
\omit \vrule height.4pt\textcolor[rgb]{0,.5,1}{\leaders\vrule\hfil}\vrule \cr
```

Explanation: `\cline` does `\noalign{\kern -rulewidth}` after the "line-row" is done. So, the following cells overlap the `\cline` output. We can try first to add `\noalign{\kern.4pt}` after `\cline` to compensate the negative kern. But first light-blue cell is not continuous in such case. The hole is here. So, the second attempt is to "fill this hole" by the code above.